# Image rotate during save() imagine php

Tags: php, file-upload, php-imagine

I use the imagine library to manage the sizing of images.

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
$imagine->open($file)
        ->thumbnail(new Imagine\Image\Box(1000, 2000), Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)
         ->save($file);
```

I use the following function to generate a thumbnail with proper dimensions. However, on some images (only), the images turn over 90 degrees (here an image of 3024x4032). Do you know how to keep the orientation ? (I did not find an option in the documentation).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to check the image orientation (getImageOrientation) and eventualy rotate it on your own

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation